# Convert raw bytes to audio in Matlab

Tags: android, matlab, sockets, audio, tcp

Here's the problem: I send a small audio file (~10Kb) from android to matlab through tcp socket. The matlab script get the file, but android's outputstream sends raw byte. How can I reconstruct the original audio file in matlab?

Comment: You need to specify the file format - float or int? how many bits per sample? what sampling rate? any information can help

Comment: Here's the details:

OutputFormat=MPEG_4
AudioEncoder=AAC
Bitrate=16
SamplingRate=44100

I'm recording the sound with Mediarecorder

Comment: Sorry for the repost,but I had problem to edit the post. I have to do the fft/xcross on the audio, so I think it has to be float!

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the android sdk, so you still have to find out if the output is raw audio samples, in which case you just have to read it as 16 bit signed integer in matlab, or is it the AAC file format, in which case you need to call some 3rd party audio converter from matlab (e.g, ffmpeg).

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have here is of the variables type.

Over TCP most probably the audio data are sent as `16int` or `16uint` (assuming that there are functions/methods that properly transform `16int` or `16uint` to bytes in order to be written to the buffer to be sent over TCP).

First of all you will have to check:

- The endian that the data are sent
- The type that the audio data have in android (most probably `16int` but check it just in case)

Then, you will have to read these data from a file and transform it in doubles. For that purpose there are quite a few examples out there. A most simple approach will be to map the values into a new range after you just convert them to doubles with the `double` function of MATLAB.

For mapping values there is the [`mapminmax` method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mapminmax.html)

Comment: I'm going to see the endianess, but I'm pretty sure that the bytes from android are sent as `8int`!

Comment: What I mean, is that you have to check the android's audio API what values have as output. Are they 16uint? 16int?

Comment: I've checked the android's API and there's no mention of what type of values has as output. Well, I can try with `16int` and if it doesn't work, with `16uint`. The endiannes should be the big one. Now, how can I proceed? Thanks for the help!